# Tic-Tac-Toe in PSPACE

Tags: complexity-theory, np, recursion, space-complexity

Why is a game like Tic-Tac-Toe in PSPACE? For example for a nxn grid you have nxn! possible game tree paths (duplicates and illegal moves aside), then don't you need (n^2)! memory slots?

Answer (score 2):

An $n\times n$ grid takes $n^2$ memory cells. You don't need to remember the "history" of the game, as it is irrelevant.

Comment: Also: PSPACE = NPSPACE is perhaps relevant?

Comment: Not relevant at all

Comment: Unless you are talking about the problem of simulating an optimal AI

Comment: I think you do need history because in general you can use backtracking depth-first search to solve a game. If so, that means you need $(n×n)^2 = n^4$ memory cells to solve tic-tac-toe, which is still in PSPACE.

Comment: you are talking about creating an algorithm that plays optimally Tic-Tac-Toe?

Comment: @nirshahar No, I am confused with "guess the solution in pol space" type of arguments to show a game is in PSPACE.

Comment: @HendrikJan Can you please define formally the language of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @nirshahar Sorry, this is not my question, I cannot really help here. I was just reflecting on your earlier answer.

Comment: @HendrikJan oh right, didn't notice that :p, sorry!

Comment: But I guess you are right